# Error using devise_token_auth gem Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

So I'm trying to generate a token for my Rails 7 app with `devise_token_auth` and I found this gem but I get this error and I understand that the gem is no longer updated:

```
Fetchings gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies....
Bundler could not finde compatible versions from gem "rails":
    In Gemfile:
        rails (~> 7.0.1)

    devise_token_auth was resolved to 0.1.21.alpha2, which depends on
        rails (~> 4.1.4)
```

So what can I do about it?
Are there more gems like `devise_token_auth`? I can fix it without chainging my Rails version?

Thanks!

Comment: yes it means that it doesn't support your version of rails; and no, stackoverflow will not recommend a tool, we don't even know what you want to achieve

Answer (score 15):

The latest version of devise_token_auth on rubygems (1.2.0) doesn't support rails 7, but the latest code on GitHub does support rails 7.

Try adding the gem like this

```
gem 'devise_token_auth', '>= 1.2.0', git: "https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth"
```